# How would I invert particles.js based off of a background (video)

Tags: javascript, html, css

How would I invert the color of particles.js based off of the color of whatever is behind it?

I have a video set as the background behind particles.js but want to make sure that it is visible by inverting the color of particles.js, heres a picture as example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/myGFF.jpg

Thank you!

Was asked to post code so here it is: https://mega.nz/folder/p9MCkbQT#4Ribz2H5vfHlNovFCRQ-DA

Comment: Please put enough code into your question so we can see the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example